Can't boot Raspberry 5 from USB SSD
Like many others, I seem to have difficulties with having my Raspberry Pi 5 to boot from SSD. There are several threads out there discussing the issue, but until now, I haven't been able to find any that works for me. I need help.
What works: booting from SD-card...
When I boot from SD-card, I'm able to see my SSD:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─sda2        8:2    0   931G  0 part /
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   512M  0 part
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.2G  0 part

Both SD-card and SSD are flashed from Raspberry Pi Imager v1.8.5:
RASPBERRY PI 5 -> RASPBERRY PI OS LITE (64-BIT)
What I have done after booting with SD-card:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt full-upgrade
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo raspi-config        #the current Version: 20240708
    
    ├──6 Advanced Options       (Configure advanced settings)
        └─ A4 Boot Order        (Choose SD, network, USB or NVMe device boot priority)
            └─ B2 NVMe/USB      (Boot Boot from NVMe before trying USB and then SD Card)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo reboot

I removed the SD card. The only thing that happens now is that the green ligt flashes two times and goes solid green. Exactly as in @swerve-driven's post, Unable to boot from USB on raspberry pi 5 . I can see activity with my USB-drive (the SSD status light flashes a couple of times but turn to solid) initially, but it does not boot.
Some power related data on my system with the only USB SSD connected (for the sake of honesty, - No, I don't use the official power supply):
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd pmic_read_adc
 3V7_WL_SW_A current(0)=0.00000000A
   3V3_SYS_A current(1)=0.14443760A
   1V8_SYS_A current(2)=0.19811380A
  DDR_VDD2_A current(3)=0.00683151A
  DDR_VDDQ_A current(4)=0.00000000A
   1V1_SYS_A current(5)=0.23715100A
    0V8_SW_A current(6)=0.32986440A
  VDD_CORE_A current(7)=0.91085990A
   3V3_DAC_A current(17)=0.00000000A
   3V3_ADC_A current(18)=0.00000000A
   0V8_AON_A current(16)=0.00537240A
      HDMI_A current(22)=0.02796090A
 3V7_WL_SW_V volt(8)=3.64781100V
   3V3_SYS_V volt(9)=3.31003300V
   1V8_SYS_V volt(10)=1.81684800V
  DDR_VDD2_V volt(11)=1.10586000V
  DDR_VDDQ_V volt(12)=0.60219720V
   1V1_SYS_V volt(13)=1.10366200V
    0V8_SW_V volt(14)=0.80073180V
  VDD_CORE_V volt(15)=0.72151340V
   3V3_DAC_V volt(20)=3.31318300V
   3V3_ADC_V volt(21)=3.31043600V
   0V8_AON_V volt(19)=0.79912020V
      HDMI_V volt(23)=5.07860000V
     EXT5V_V volt(24)=5.06922000V
      BATT_V volt(25)=0.00000000V
      
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_throttled
    throttled=0x0


Update 1: More output (blkid; /etc/fstab; /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt)
blkid
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="bootfs" LABEL="bootfs" UUID="91FE-7499" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a870914a-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="56f80fa2-e005-4cca-86e6-19da1069914d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a870914a-02"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="56f80fa2-e005-4cca-86e6-19da1069914d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="16a1d456-02"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="bootfs" LABEL="bootfs" UUID="91FE-7499" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="16a1d456-01"

/etc/fstab
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /etc/fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 314 Jul  4 02:14 /etc/fstab

/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=16a1d456-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait cfg80211.ieee80211_regdom=SE


Update 2: Content of /etc/fstab
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=a870914a-01  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=a870914a-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that


I don't get what the problem is here? What am I expected to do to boot my Raspberry Pi 5 from my USB SSD without the need of any SD-card?

"When I boot from SD-card, I'm able to see my SSD" it appears that the SSD is being used for root and firmware at this point - what is the output of blkid, the content of /etc/fstab and /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt when you boot

I updated my question @jaromanda-x and added the output.

I asked for the CONTENT of /etc/fstab  ... anyway - from the info you managed to post, looks like you HAVE booted from the SSD

Sorry, misunderstood (I'm not very familiar with this). I absolutely don't argue about where it boots from, but fact is: If I remove the SD card (but with the USB SSD still connected), then it does not boot at all.  If it is of any use, I added the information you asked for (I hope?).

I imagine the answer is no, but does it work with a blank/not-pi-image SD card?  At most, it's just using the firmware files from there, but since it is actually at least booting the OS from the SSD -- and the whole issue seems like a bug -- it might be something like there's an initial check for a card that fails even though if it passes it doesn't read anything from there.

Thanks for your comment @goldilocks. I don't know to be honest. The "solution" (buying an official power supply), didn't came into my mind in the first place. I thought I hade more than enough power with my 100 W laptop charger. In my way of looking at it, the symptoms (on lack of power) was a bit "weird".

Chargers are intended for things that already have batteries in them, which mitigate the demand for instantaneous current that computers under load can produce -- ie., just because something meets the amperage requirements does not mean it can actually provide that from nothing in X microseconds.  Boot is very power intensive.  It is interesting get_throttled showed nothing but then that may have been the context (eg., if it had only been running for a while and never under any  particular load).

BTW, please do accept your own answer when the system lets you (you may have to wait 24 hours).   If everything continues to work out, it is a real answer since the real problem would seem to be insufficient power supply.

The PARTUUID in cmdline.txt matches the SD Card.

NOTE Without an official power supply the Pi5 can only supply 600 mA which is insufficient for most SSD.

Check if the power supply is suffiecient. Insufficient power can cause boot issues.

I don't feel like I can really say this is a real answer, but it solved my problem (i e The Raspberry Pi boots) so here's what ended up working.
I got the idea from one of the comments on the youtube clip Raspberry Pi 5 USB Boot with non official power supply: "I tried all these and nothing worked except to buy the official power supply.".
That's exactly how it was for me. It wasn't enough that I used my 100W USB C laptop charger to supply power.
The solution was to buy and use the official charger, https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/27w-power-supply/.

And Raspberry Pi looks more like Apple each day! It is lunacy (or hubris?) that RPi continues to cling to powering all models via USB port - Especially when they don't implement the newer USB standards that allow delivery of more than 5 VDC to the load. A simple "barrel connector" on the Pi would be more reliable & easier in every way.
